# Trees in Prolog

Tags: tree, prolog, first-order-logic

I am studying binary trees in Prolog.

I know the structure but I don't understand this code in my slides:

```
binary_tree(void).
binary_tree(tree(_Element,Left,Right)) :-
  binary_tree(Left), binary_tree(Right).
```

This would need for recognize the tree structure.

But does "void" represent?

I tried this query

```
?- binary_tree(a).
false.
```

and assume that `a` is one node of a tree.

I'm following this resource for understanding:

https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/4

but is different to my slides.

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: try `binary_tree(A).` instead.

Comment: just assign A=void. But i think in this case void stay for "nothing", like Paulo show me in him example. @WillNess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` is an atom. It cannot assume any values (other than itself). In addition, `a`, also an atom, is not a valid tree per your predicate definition. A tree with `a` as its only node would be represented by the compound term `tree(a,void,void)`:

```
| ?- binary_tree(tree(a,void,void)).

yes
```

As another example, a balanced tree with nodes `a..g` would be represented by the term (written indented just for readability):

```
   tree(a,
       tree(b,
           tree(d,void,void),
           tree(e,void,void)
       ),
       tree(c,
           tree(f,void,void),
           tree(g,void,void)
       )
    )
```

You can verify that this term is a tree again using your `binary_tree /1` predicate:

```
| ?- binary_tree(tree(a,tree(b,tree(d,void,void),tree(e,void,void)),tree(c,tree(f,void,void),tree(g,void,void)))).

yes
```

Comment: So, ad example for a,b,c,d,e,f,g balanced tree i need to write binary_tree(tree(a, tree(b, tree(c, void, void), tree(d, void, void)), tree(e, tree(f, void, void), tree(g, void, void)))) ...in this way i have A root with 2 children B,E and B have C-D and E have F-G ?

Comment: No. Updated my answer.