# Prolog - Find the depth of an element in a binary tree

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree, depth

I would like to know how I can find the depth of a given element `E` in a binary tree.
For simplicity, the tree has no repeated elements.
I tried:

```
ElemDepth(E,t(E,T1,T2), D).
ElemDepth(E,t(M,T1,T2), D):- D1 is D+1, ElemDepth(E,T1, D1).
ElemDepth(E,t(M,T1,T2), D):- D1 is D+1, ElemDepth(E,T2, D1).
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Not an answer but this might help you to figure out an answer for yourself:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857333/2820

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I can see that the search part of the element is the same as mine, it still escapes me how and when to increase the depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a binary tree where

- The empty tree is denoted by the atom `nil`, and
- A non-empty tree is represented as a `t/3` structure:

  ```
  t( Data, Left_Subtree, Right_Subtree)
  ```

We can walk it easily:

```
visit( t(_,L,_) , P ) :- visit(L,P). % visit the left subtree, then
visit( t(P,_,_) , P ) .              % visit the current tree node, then
visit( t(_,_,R) , P ) :- visit(R,P). % visit the right subtree
```

And visiting each node whilst computing the depth of the nodes is similarly easy. We just move the actual traversal logic into a helper predicate that carries with it the extra bit of state to count depth as it goes.

```
visit(T,P,D) :- visit(T,0,P,D) .

visit( t(_,L,_) , N, P, D ) :- N1 is N+1, visit(L,N1,P,D) .
visit( t(P,_,_) , D, P, D ) .
visit( t(_,_,R) , N, P, D ) :- N1 is N+1, visit(R,N1,P,D) .
```

Comment: @Nichoals Carey I am not completely understood the meaning of the two `D` in the base case `visit( t(P,_,_) , D, P, D )` .

Comment: That second argument/parameter (`N`) of `visit/4` is the accumulator that tracks the current depth — it gets incremented (`N1 is N+1`) on every recursion. So when you are visiting the current node in the tree, we unify `D` and `N`. One could just as easily made that second clause of `visit/4` to be `visit( t(P,_,_) , D, P, D ) :- D  = N .`