# Comparing the number of nodes at a given depth in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree, depth

Given two binary trees `T1` and `T2` having the same height, I would like to know how to check if the number of nodes of `T1` is equal to the number of nodes in `T2`, for each value of depth `D`.
I wrote a predicate `numberOfNodesatD(T, N, D)` which calculates the number of nodes at a depth `D`, but I am not able to define in Prolog the equality between the number of nodes `if N1 == N2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffing off [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821059/467473) to your earlier question, [Prolog - Find the depth of an element in a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790795/prolog-find-the-depth-of-an-element-in-a-binary-tree),

We can use

```
visit(T,P,D) :- visit(T,0,P,D) .

visit( t(_,L,_) , N, P, D ) :- N1 is N+1, visit(L,N1,P,D) .
visit( t(P,_,_) , D, P, D ) .
visit( t(_,_,R) , N, P, D ) :- N1 is N+1, visit(R,N1,P,D) .
```

and do something like this:

```
node_count_by_depth(T,D,N) :-
  findall( D, visit(T,_,D), Ds ) , 
  msort(Ds,Ss)l ,
  groups(Ss,Fs) .


groups( []     , [] ) .
groups( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :- groups(Xs, X:1, Ys ).

groups( []     , Y:N , [Y:N]    ) .  % the end of the source list is a sequence break.
groups( [X|Xs] , X:N , Ys       ) :- % if we haven't hit a sequence break...
  N1 is N+1 ,                        % - increment the count
  groups(Xs,X:N1,Ys) .               % - and recurse down
groups( [X|Xs] , Y:N , [Y:N|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
  X \= Y ,                           % - we have hit a sequence break,
  groups(Xs,X:1,Ys)                  % - recurse down, having moved the tuple to the result list
  .                                  % Easy!
```

And once you have that, then it's a matter of:

```
same_number_of_nodes_at_depth(T1,T2,D,N) :-
  node_count_by_depth(T1,L1),
  node_count_by_depth(T2,L2),
  member( D:N, L1 ),
  member( D:N, L2 ).
```